# Why does adding a listing above another mess up the formatting of the original

Tags: listings

The following Latex produces about what I expect:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\title{test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lstdefinestyle{cs}{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  breaklines=true,
  framextopmargin=1pt,
  framexbottommargin=1pt,
  frame=tb,
  framesep=3pt,
  framerule=0pt,
  showstringspaces=false,
  tabsize=4,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  numbers=left,
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=8pt,
  language=[Sharp]C,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{green!50!black},
  stringstyle=\color{red},}

\begin{lstlisting}[prebreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space},frame=single,caption={Test caption},captionpos=b]
1       2372065 1       R       52.21   52.21   0.00    1       2       0       0       0       0       0       8       9       0       0       0       0       14      0       0       0       0       0       0       21      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if I add a second listing above it it seems to ruin the original listing. See below for example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\title{test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lstdefinestyle{cs}{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  breaklines=true,
  framextopmargin=1pt,
  framexbottommargin=1pt,
  frame=tb,
  framesep=3pt,
  framerule=0pt,
  showstringspaces=false,
  tabsize=4,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  numbers=left,
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=8pt,
  language=[Sharp]C,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{green!50!black},
  stringstyle=\color{red},}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=cs]
public Contract(int cID, string tc)
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[prebreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space},frame=single,caption={Test caption},captionpos=b]
1       2372065 1       R       52.21   52.21   0.00    1       2       0       0       0       0       0       8       9       0       0       0       0       14      0       0       0       0       0       0       21      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This only happens if I add the style to the top listing. Why does this happen and how can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: I've trimmed it down to first one using `breaklines=true` and the second one using `frame=single`.  But I don't know why or how to fix it.

Comment: Definitely sound like a bug. I think you should also send an email to the maintainer